# Getting error while running 50 MB script on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a script to update the DB, that script is approx
50 MB in size and contains some about 800,000 lines.

Error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Cannot execute script.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
>   (mscorlib)

Can somebody please help me to run this script without getting this error?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

use the command-line tool SQLCMD which is much leaner on memory. It is as simple as:

```
SQLCMD -d <database-name> -i filename.sql
```

You need valid credentials to access your SQL Server instance or even to access a database

Comment: when i tried it by using above code it is giving me some error,
Msg 4060, Level 11, State 1, Server (my PC login name), Line 1
Cannot open database "(local)" requested by the login. The login failed. Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server (my PC login name), Line 1 Login failed for user 'my login user name'.

Comment: because the answer was wrong, is the database for argument "-d"

Comment: I use SQLCMD -d master -i D:\BankMaster.sql for new database

Comment: You can also specify an output file using the -o parameter. 

SQLCMD -d database -i filename.sql -o result.txt

Comment: With user credentials SQLCMD -s .\sqlent1 -U username -P password -d database -i script.sql

Comment: and if you need to specify the port, it would be <ComputerName>\<InstanceName>,<port>

Answer (score 62):

Adding to @user1293068's answer, I needed to specify the instance name. Here is my full syntax:

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -d <DatabaseName> -i <MyScript.sql>
```

This is documented on Technet's [Use the sqlcmd Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) article.

(Note that you must enter a switch value of "-S", not "-s". The switch is case-sensitive.)

Comment: example of what I used  -->   `C:\Users\tstick\Documents>sqlcmd -S server.subdomain.companyname.com,4184 -d ebimap -i SQLscript.sql`

Comment: It looks like the default instance name (MSSQLSERVER) needs to be excluded to connect, e.g. `sqlcmd -S localhost -d db` and not `sqlcmd -S localhost\MSSQLSERVER -d db`

Comment: +1 I also needed to add `-x` because my script contains `$(` - from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12301822/36036

Comment: Extra +1 for pointing out the switch is case sensitive

Answer (score 16):

If credentials are required

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -U <username> -P <password> -d <DatabaseName> -i <MyScript.sql>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also try increasing the Maximum Server Memory value in server properties.  
To edit this setting, right click on server name and select Properties > Memory tab.

I encountered this error trying to execute a `30MB` SQL script in SSMS 2012.
 After increasing the value from `1024MB` to `2048MB` I was able to run the script.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: cannot verify this myself.    "user does not have permission to perform this action"

Answer (score 6):

Ok, none of the answers were sufficient to get my script successfully restoring.

So:

1. Ensure that your network account has sufficient permissions to access both SQL Server instance and the specific database you intend to restore.
2. It's best that the database you intend to restore actually exists, if it was merely generated from Generate Scripts (with modifications to include both Schema and Data)
3. Run the command-line tool in Administrator mode (if necessary), e.g., type CMD from Run on the start menu
4. In the command-line tool, type something like `"SQLCMD -d CMS -i C:\Carnotaurus\Data\script.sql"`. Here, `CMS` is the name of the database I intend to restore and `"C:\Carnotaurus\Data\script.sql"` is the full file path of the restore script that was generated by the Generate Scripts in SMSS.

I hope this clears-up a few missing steps.

Answer (score 1):

Open command Prompt

sqlcmd -S servername -i C:\Users\mycomputer\Downloads\script\yourscript.sql -d datebasename