# Escape sequence for $ (dollar sign) in T-sql script

Tags: t-sql, powershell

I am running a T-SQL script, called from a powershell script, that contains a text row which includes a sequence containing $(MV).

When I run the script I get the error "'MV' scripting variable not defined." which I assume is because it interpretates the $(MV) string as a variable instead of being a part of the text string.

How can I write the dollar sign as an escape sequence? Is that possible in a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the backtick character to escape a $ sign in PowerShell:

```
`$
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the escape character for T-SQL for a $ sign.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread. I've used CHAR(36) instead of a $ before, e.g. 'Text' + CHAR(36) + 'MoreText'. Bit hacky I know...

Answer (score 10):

Are you executing the script with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)?  It will interpret $(variablename) and try to expand it.

You can disable this using the -x command-line option.

Oh, if you're using [Invoke-Sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) you can use the -DisableVariables parameter.

I was assuming you didn't want to have the sqlcmd variable substitution done.  If you were just trying to get the $ past Powershell, use the back-tick (`$) as in another suggestion.