# Powershell name with $

Tags: powershell

so i want to check something with a "$" in the name.
But $ creates an variable, is it somehow possible to not create a variable? So interacting with the e.g. Test$Name because if I try to work with it so dothis name="Test$Name" then it will create a Variable

Thank you

Comment: Escape the `$` sign with a grave-accent(`).

Comment: Or use single quotes for liter strings `$name='Test$Name'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape sequence for $ (dollar sign) in T-sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296905/escape-sequence-for-dollar-sign-in-t-sql-script)

Answer (score 0):

'Test$Name'

"Test$( [char]36 )Name"

Comment: Though the second one works, isn't it easier to use "Test`$Name"?

Comment: Absolutely. Just another means of doing it, that's all.