# How to solve System.OutOfMemoryException in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

My scenario is my live database is on Azure database name `vlproduction` and I am using SQL Server 2014 on my local machine, database name `testvlproduction`. For some reason, my `testvlproduction` database was deleted.

I want to generate `testvlproduction` to be the same as `vlproduction` but I found there is no way to take direct backup of live so I generate script with data but script is too big (300mb) whenever I'm trying to run script on my local it shows

[System.OutOfMemoryException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LrID.gif)

Please tell me, what to do to fix this ? or is there another way to generate database same as live on local

Is there already built any such functionality in SQL Server?

May be this question repeated but still I have no solution for my issue.

Fill free to ask any query.

Thanks

Comment: im not sure in azure but in AWS there's a SCALE UP preferences which increase the memory/cpu in a certain circumstances.

Comment: Instead of committing all the Scripts on go . Just take in batch wise and commit in small batches.

Comment: but issue is on my local machine not on azure

Comment: i checked this one too but there is more then 28000 lines  @mohan111

Comment: If you keep database tables in memory (since SQL Server 2014 allows this) and the size is too big for in-memory tables, it might be a problem on your local computer with limited resources.

Comment: yes I agree but if you are going to see in task manager while executing this script SSMS CPU cost will hugely increased and Memory Buffer will be occupied. So try to clear log files in your Server some what space you can get

Comment: I think that's a *management studio* error, not a server one per se. Have you tried running your scripts through a command line tool like `sqlcmd`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307435/getting-error-while-running-50-mb-script-on-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: i tried sqlcmd tool but it also shows error @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: `Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.`  it  shows error @mohan111

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of sql server,This happen because Management Studio is running out of memory, not the SQL Server service.
This is likely caused by the size of the result set that you are returning to Management Studio.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2874903for more details.
For more [sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files)

Answer (score 0):

Since your SSMS runs out of memory you should try it with the a new [release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx). It should be compatible with SQL Server 2014.

If you have some idle time on your production database take a db backup and restore it locally - use [Export Data Tier Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213241.aspx) and select the proper version where you want to restore. If this is not an option for you I'd suggest to take @mohan111 's suggestion of committing your script in batches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two problems:

1. System out of memory exception - This usually happens while running big scripts in SSMS. One work around is to run it using command prompt using sqlcmd command (see the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx)
2. Creating Test Database with the same schema as that of production - You can make use of SSDT tool in Visual Studio. This will help you to create a database project which mimics the production database and you can use the publish functionality to create database where ever required which will have the same schema